# Possible to create JSR 286 portlet using Coldfusion?

Tags: java, coldfusion, portlet, liferay

I was just thinking this morning, since ColdFusion is essentially built on JAVA, is it possible to create JSR 286 portlets using coldfusion?

A search revealed that it might be possible, but I cannot find any material on this?

Reason I ask is because I would love to be able to create Liferay compatible portlets with ColdFusion, as I am not a JAVA dev.

Thoughts? Does anyone have any tutorials or references on this subject?

**EDIT**

Is there anyways to get CF portlets without CF running in the container? I'm curious how this would work with having only one license of CF.  Would I need another license to run under liferay (if I can even run in liferay?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on CF9 I think you can just extend CFIDE.portlets.ColdFusionPortlet

Here is a handout on it...

[Building Portlets With ColdFusion](http://www.petefreitag.com/presentations/max/2009/Pete_Freitag_Building_Portlets_With_ColdFusion_handout.pdf)

Comment: It doesn't mention how it compiles it into a portlet you can deploy outside of JBOSS?  I would need this specifically for other Java based apps like Liferay, where I can hot-deploy the portlet just by putting the .war file into the deploy folder.

Comment: Does this help?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WS87867FAA-B7C3-4cea-9947-E24245DDA659.html

Answer (score 0):

You might try this website: http://wiki.cfinnovate.com/display/cfmlportlets/Home

I saw this presentation at CFObjective 2009 and if I remember correctly, Adam was running portlets in websphere. But you will need to have CF deployed in the container, obviously